# Mixing useQuery clients in client and server component in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a problem with mixing query clients from `useQuery` in server and client components in NextJS.
I have a server component that prefetches data:

```js
export default async function HouseholdChooser() {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();
  await queryClient.prefetchQuery({
    queryKey: ['households'],
    queryFn: getHouseholds,
  });
  
  return (
    <div className="grid flex-1 gap-2">
      <HydrationBoundary state={dehydrate(queryClient)}>
        <HouseholdsList />
      </HydrationBoundary>
   </div>
  );
```

and a client component `HouseholdsList`:

```js
const HouseholdsList = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['households'],
    queryFn: getHouseholds,
  });

  if (data?.error) {
    toast({ title: data.error.message });
  }

  return (
    <>
      {data.map(({ id, name }) => (
        <Link key={id} href={`/households/${id}`} className="hover:bg-accent p-1">
          {name}
        </Link>
      ))}
    </>
  );
```

I also have an adding component:

```js
const AddHousehold = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const mutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: createHousehold,
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ['households']})
    }
  })
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    mutation.mutate(data);
  };
```

the problem I'm facing is that my `invalidateQueries` doesn't work.
I assume it is because in my server component (`HouseholdChooser`) I'm using `new QueryClient()` (but I can't use the `useQueryClient()` there, because it is server side component).
How should I handle this type of problem in NextJS+useQuery?

Would it be appropiate to both `invalidateQueries` and `revalidatePath` in `action` method or we should not mix them two?
I can't really find any resource to get to know any good practices in mixing NextJS with useQuery so would be grateful for any advice.